# better to use one 3d array or two 2d?

Tags: java, performance, multidimensional-array

if i want to store two values in a 2d array, is it better (memory and speed-wise) to use one 3d array to store the values? or two 2d arrays? eg:

```
int[][][] array = new int[rows][cols][data];

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        array[i][j][0] = value1;
        array[i][j][1] = value2;
    }
```

or

```
int[][] array1 = new int[rows][cols];
int[][] array2 = new int[rows][cols];

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        array1[i][j] = value1;
        array2[i][j] = value2;
    }
```

or wouldnt it really matter in terms of performance?

they arent massive arrays that i am using, only a hundred by a hundred at the most probably.. but if it was to scale up, which would be the best to use?

or, if performance wont be affected at all, which would be considered the best coding practice?

EDIT: this is related specifically to a java project, but more just interested in general; if there are different languages that would make a difference depending on the method used, that information could be useful as well for future reference..

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). - Knuth

Comment: It would be better to make classes representing your data and working with those as opposed to making obscure references to data contained in arrays

Comment: @Elliot, interesting link, but i am more interested what is considered the general practice, as i am currently just learning.

Comment: @Rogue and Vladmir, it is just for a quick matrix to help with a calculation, i just need to store the value and the number of datapoints used to calculate it. once i have used the matrix i never need that data again, so i dont think writing a whole class just for two numbers is worth it. or is it? i am relatively new to java..

Comment: @guskenny83 as you've asked about the general practice, using a class for representing data in a particular form -is- the common practice. Arrays are rarely used for data management compared to objects and high-level data structures

Comment: You should always, ALWAYS choose the representation that represents your data correctly. If you try to represent 3d-data, use a 3d-data structure. If you try to represent 2d-data, use a 2d-data structure. Never ever choose less-representative(aka bad-designed) code for performance reason, see @Elliot 's link

Comment: thanks everyone, its not very much extra work and if it is considered best practice then i will get in the habit of creating classes for all my data. its a bit tricky coming to object oriented programming after learning mostly C. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing what you really want to achieve, I would say that what you need is to place an object with the relevant data in the matrix (provided that is the best description of your problem area). This would mean.

```
class MeasurePoint {
  int temperature;  // For example
  int windSpeed;

  MeasurePoint(int a, int b) {
    temperature = a;
    windSpeed = b;
  }
}

MeasurePoint[][] map = new MeasurePoint[rows][cols];

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      map[i][j] = new MeasurePoint(value1, value2);
    }
}
```

Java is object oriented. Take advantage of the modelling tools you have at your disposal. If you just want to traverse memory, you are just as well off with assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier and would scale better is you define a class to hold your values and then store them in a Vector or an ArrayList of them.

For example

```
class Values {
    int value1;
    int value2;
}

ArrayList<Values> valueList = new ArrayList<Values>()

for (int i = 0, i <= 100, i++) {
    currentValue = Values();
    currentValue.value1 = i + 1;
    currentValue.value2 = i + 2;
    valueList[i] = currentValue;
}
```

In terms of performance, depending on how you traverse your 2d or your 3d array, you could get a linear or a quadratic order performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this using `Map`s. You can contain all the data for a row using a Row class

```
public class Row {

    protected int id;
    protected Object other;
    //etc, getters/setters, whatever you need

}

Map<Integer, Row> rows = new HashMap<>();

//...
Row r = this.rows.get(/*row id*/);
if (r == null) {
    //row doesn't exist
} else {
    //work with row object
}
```